# bundle format not recognized

Tags: ios, xcode, git-checkout, codesign

when I checked out a project from server, and will run it. I met a issue is    :

> ***Code sign error*** /Users/PanChao/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/YZTUser-cvcnntqoopwxrtcxdnabdqzxtllp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MWPhotoBrowser.bundle:
>   bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable Command
>   /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1 .

I spend many hours to fix it ,but this error is alway exist! if anyone knows that how to fixed it, please help me thanks .

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: Also check this answer, maybe it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these following things

1.your bundle ID should be valid.

2.your provisioning profile should be valid.

3.your certificate should work.

Answer (score 0):

In your pod project,find the target which goes wrong,and correct the Identity and Signing area by choosing infolist and signing profile.This works fine for me

[the result should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVmSG.png)

Comment: sorry， understand you words , but i don't know how to fixed my error issue. Can you tell me fixed it specific steps? For example first step is ... and next step is ... think you very  much!