# Problems including third party framework in XCode 9

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xcode9, ios-frameworks

I've been trying to include a third party framework in my ios app archive and I've been running into a few problems. The framework was downloaded as a zip file, extracted and copied to my desktop. Here's an image of it's file contents:

[image]

Heres a description of the problems I am facing:

1. When I drag the framework from my desktop and drop it under the frameworks folder inside my target, the app build fine on the simulator and the app can access the library. However, when I archive the app and build for a generic device, the framework never makes it inside my app bundle (app.ipa) and the library is missing in the distributed app
2. So I deleted it from my frameworks and added it through the "embedded binaries" part like so:

[image]

This caused it to reappear inside the "link frameworks and libraries" as well as the frameworks group inside my target, like so:

[image]

This also creates a new build phase for Embedded Frameworks like so:

[image]

Now, when I go to build it for a simulator or generic device, I get the following errors:

[image]

And when I go to archive it for a generic device I get the following error:

[image]

and

[image]

It is an Objective-C framework so I am importing the library inside my Bridging Header like so:

[image]

Here is the documentation for the framework I am trying to install

[image]

Any help or advice is much appreciated. I've been stuck on this for quite some time and I think i'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Did you properly setup your bridging header inside Build Settings?

Comment: Yes, the build settings is correctly referencing the bridging header

Comment: I believe you already did some research about this issue, but if not try next links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable; https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html (section Importing External Frameworks). You should write `import TrustDefender` in each file, which uses it.

Comment: Urgh, I tried that, switched the bridging header to import the files but now I get a different error:


Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_THMProfileStatus", referenced from:

Comment: check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64