# Xcode Build Failing due to "bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a dilemma in regards to not being able to run a React Native project in Xcode because of an error that I have spent days trying to resolve.

I have attached a screenshot of the error [image: screenshot of build error in Xcode]

It is stating that:

> "/Users/diamoniquedanner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Entrepreneur-elimewlshojayqdyaklhiziodxbi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Entrepreneur.app:
>   bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable Command
>   /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1"

I would like to state that this project was handed to me by a client and I have tried creating anew provisioning profile, create a new certificate, etc. (however I may be doing it wrong) and I cannot contact the old team for any resources.

Best regards,
Dia'Monique

Comment: in embeddded binaries there is some framework? have you tried to delete DerivedData?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting the DerivedData folder, cleaning the project and trying again.

If that doesn't work, you can:

- Select the Pods Project
- In the main editor window, select the Pod in the targets dropdown
- Under the general tab, and under the identity header, click choose Info.plist file
- Select the plist file for the Pod

Answer (score 0):

More of exploratatory questions than an answer per say.

There a lot of question on stackoverflow with the same error. Did you try the solution outlined in those:
- [Code sign error : bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)
- [Xcode - Bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable/38751921)

Are there any error or warning in the build before the code signing step?

Answer (score 0):

Like most of them have replied one main issue could the be the difference of the IOS versions it was created thus the derived data could be conflicting . As for the first step delete any derived that on your previous versions  and also delete any builds . If you are using any specific files with a common target make sure you have not duplicated them as well . Clean and build the folder .

As far as frameworks go , Make sure you have the frameworks in these 3 places in this order

**General tab:**

-Embedded Binaries ,

-Linked Frameworks and Libraries

**Build Phases tab**:

-Embed Frameworks

Also if you currently have any frameworks in **Embedded binaries** remove them from that and add to **Liked Frameworks and Libraries section**

Answer (score 0):

I just remove the framework from the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedied Content", then add it back again.

It works. I don't know why, maybe it's a Xcode bug.