# How to fix: "bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable"

Tags: c++, xcode, sfml, macos-catalina

I create project to school and after update my MacOS to Catalina SFML start doesn't work.

i had been used this links at my project still doesn't work.

[Code sign error : bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29271548/code-sign-error-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable)

[Xcode - Bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720234/xcode-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable/38751921)

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5742

https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-iOS/issues/363

/Users/nintyswinty/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SFML-gsdieoedqhlmxqahfxqzujzewoid/Build/Products/Debug/SFML.app/Contents/Frameworks/sfml-window.framework/Versions/A: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
to see what and  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). 
if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt.

Comment: contact the framework [support community](https://www.sfml-dev.org/community.php)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255716/1040347