# Xcode 11.2.1 - Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, macos, sfml, code-signing

I'm working on a SFML app for macOS with the latest Xcode version.

I got a `"Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code"` error when it tries to sign the SFML frameworks. I added these under "Link Binary with Libraries" and "Copy Files" in Target, under Build Phases. Before, I was working with my local frameworks under `/Library/Frameworks`, and it was working very well.

Now I need to create an archive `.app`.
I've tried a lot of things seen on other posts here (like lock and unlock my keychains), but nothing worked. Still got that error.

My SFML Frameworks in "Link Binary with Libraries"
[image: "Link Binary with Libraries"]

> /Users/lounesksouri/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Squadro-gqwjbvsooypqaifxxyzhdrahkdpo/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Squadro/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Squadro.app/Contents/Frameworks/sfml-system.framework/Versions/A: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
>
> Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Do you have your framework under the `Embed Frameworks` area?
check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52787285/1040347

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov I had seen this post, and I think the "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" under General tab is quite the same thing (as in my Xcode version, there's not "Embed Framework" area in the Builder Phases tab), so yes all my frameworks are listed in this section...

Comment: To make sure, do you have under `Targets/Build Phases/Embedded Frameworks` your sfml frameworks?

Comment: Did you try to delete Derived Data under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` ? (xcode should be closed) via terminal command `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov yes, I did try a lot of times to delete Derived Data. And I don't have the `Targets/Build Phases/Embedded Frameworks` section

Comment: I suppose it is a framework's issue, as [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58738867/how-to-fix-bundle-format-unrecognized-invalid-or-unsuitable) is experiencing the same issue.
So it is better to contact them [directly](https://www.sfml-dev.org/community.php) they even have a Discord channel

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov Thanks for your help, I finally got a solution (see my answer) !

Comment: Glad, you solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem, after long hours.

It's a lot more simple to use the script already present in `Build Phases` tab, generated if you use the `SFML App` Xcode template (see [here](https://pastebin.com/JfNYcizD) the original script). I had tried it at first, but it didn't work so I let it down.

But, in this script, the first three lines are not the good ones, for a normal SFML installation on macOS. We need to modify these lines with the good paths to the  `Frameworks` and `lib` folders, as follows :

```sh
SFML_DEPENDENCIES_INSTALL_PREFIX="/Library/Frameworks"
CMAKE_INSTALL_FRAMEWORK_PREFIX="/Library/Frameworks"
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIB_PREFIX="/usr/local/lib"
FRAMEWORKS_FULL_PATH="$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH/"
```

Secondly, there is still the code signing problem : the archive will created but we will get an error if we start the `.app`. The solution to this problem is to check `Disable Library Validation` under `Target/Signing & Capabilities` to allow the application to `load plug-ins or frameworks signed by other developers`.

Finally, if we create the archive and launch the application, everything goes normally, as planned.

Comment: This part helped me a lot, for the code signing I just resigned the SFML libs with my identity. (see my answer below)

Comment: Thank you. There is one more thing that you may need to change if still have the problem. Under the **Build Settings->Other Code Signing Flags** put `--deep` for **Any SDK** variant for the version selected (Debug or Release)

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem with the new update of Xcode. I was reading your discussion, and did some accidental modifications. I am definetely not an expert but what I did fixed the problem so I did not receive tgis error anymore. So I added the sfml libraries (5 libraries), whose paths are written in build settings -> framework swarch paths. And this adding automatically added them in Embedded Frameworks under the Build phases section. What I did is unchecking the checkboxes of all 5 libraries "Code sign On copy". Thank you guys for giving me the path for "solving" the problem :))))

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to upvote if the answer worked for you 

Comment: This act dont permit to trust your device and your app doesnt installed..

Answer (score 0):

For the Code-signing issue:

1. Open a Terminal,
2. Go to the Framework folder (`cd /Library/Frameworks`) and sing them.
3. choose your identity

```
security find-identity -vp codesigning
```

4. sign them Frameworks!

```
codesign -s AD90FAFAFAFAFAFAFAF-YOURHASH-9D6 ogg.framework
codesign ... all the others
```

5. run and enjoy!