# Xcode 12.5 (12E262) "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" after a .scn file added to ARKit project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, codesign

I have this anoying build fail with an error: `Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code`

I am using Xcode 12.5 (12E262).

This happened when I converted a .dae file to .scn and added it to my ARKit project (instead of a default ship.scn).

The error appears only when I trying to run the project on my physical device(iPhone 11 pro) but it runs successfully on a simulated device.
I don't use pods or any external frameworks in this project.

I tried this solutions with no success:
[Stack1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421999/xcode-10-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code) and [Stack2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253591/xcode-11-2-1-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code).
Apple documentation wasn't helpful.

Sorry for bad Eng. I am trying my best to improve both ways - non-native language and a programming language :)
Please - do your magic!

Answer (score 1):

Actually - I'm finally found a solution! To be more precise - a combination of solutions!
Work's for me when I followed exact sequence:

1. (Optional) Go to **Xcode Preferences -> Locations** tab and make sure that the **Command Line Tools** is set (to Xcode 12.5 (12E262) in my case).
2. Open a **terminal** and run:

   ​`rm -rf Users/yourUserFolder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*`

   then cd to your project folder and run `xattr -cr`
3. Open a **Keychain Access** and delete all items from a **"login"** keychain.
4. Go to **Xcode Product -> Clean Build Folder** and **close the Xcode**.
5. Reboot the PC (was very important in my case!)
6. Build\Run your project.

Since this steps were made - I haven't had this error anymore.