# Xcode 13.4.1 (13F100) "Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code" which certificate I should delete?

Tags: ios, xcode

sorry if I redact more than I need to, I’m an idiot beginner.

I tried to run a test project on my own physical iPhone but ran into a Command CodeSign error.  Researched a bit, [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602643/xcode-12-5-12e262-command-codesign-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-after-a) looks like I can try deleting duplicate/redundant certificates.  As you can see in the screenshot, not 1, not 2 but my Xcode has 3 seemingly duplicate certificates. My question is: are they really all the same? I see that I am signed in with a certifcate dated Aug 2021. Should I delete the new ones or keep the latest one that is expiring in Sep 2031?  I am very worried that I will shoot myself in the foot if I delete the wrong ones.

(If this doesn’t work, I would have to delete and and reinstall Xcode completely.  It would take a lot of time as my MacBook is an older model.  So any advice to avoid that will be greatly appreciated.  I already spending way too much time on this “side error” instead of actually practicing/learning Swift. It’s soul crushing. )

BIG THANKS in advance.

[image]
[image]

Edit:
[image]

Comment: Can you click on your target, hit the "Signing & Capabilities" tab and take a screenshot?

Comment: Note that reinstalling Xcode won't do anything to the certificates in your Keychain. They will be left the same.

Comment: Hi @JeshuaLacock Screenshot attached :)

Comment: I'd suggest going to the Accounts preferences (your 3rd image) press the + button and choose add Development or Distribution certificate (depending on what your current needs are). It should then show a valid date for your certificate which it currently does not.

Comment: IT WORKS! THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH!!!  If you would like to put your help in an answer, I am more than happy to put the green checkmark on it.  :)

Comment: Cheers, thanks and glad you got it working. A number of things can cause this, so we got lucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest going to the Accounts preferences (your 3rd image) press the + button and choose add Development or Distribution certificate (depending on what your current needs are).

It should then show a valid date for your certificate which it currently does not.